# Priority queue constructor java with lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, constructor, priority-queue

I am trying to create a priority queue for a class Student with some order using lambda expression comparator of java 1.8.
But I am getting error Cannot infer type arguments for PriorityQueue<>

```
class Priority
{
    PriorityQueue<Student> priorityQueue = null;
    public Priority()
    {
        priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(
            (Student s1,Student s2)->{
                int cmp = 0;
                if (s1.cgpa !=s2.cgpa)
                {
                    return ( s2.cgpa - s1.cgpa);
                }
                else if (s1.name.compareTo(s2.name) != 0)
                {
                    return s1.name.compareTo(s2.name);
                } 
                else
                {
                    return (s1.id - s2.id);
                }       
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me: https://ideone.com/gtnccM

Comment: Note that your implementation does not properly handle overflows. It would be better to use [`Comparator.comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-)`(Student::getCgpa).`[`thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.function.Function-)`(Student::getName).`[`thenComparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-)`(Student::getId)`, which is also simpler.